# Play m3u8 file in HTML5 mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-video

I have an m3u8 streaming url that I need to play it in and android HTML5 application. I can play the stream in VLC on both computer and mobile, but I cannot stream it with html5 video player.

```
<video width="640" height="360">
<source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://myfile.m3u8" />
</video>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: It does not give me any errors, it s just not playing the stream.

Comment: Which player are you using?

Comment: I am using HTML5 Player  .

Comment: If I am not mistaken you need to use a Player to handle that if the source is external but I could be completely wrong here.

Comment: Yes,It is an external URL, but  what player do you suggest me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is using this cordova plugin to stream the url using the native mobile player
https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 video player can only play .mp4 or .webm. In addition, .m3u8 is not a video file, it is a *plain text* file used describe where media files are located.

You need to parse the .m3u8 file, get the URLs of the videos and play those with the HTML video player.

Comment: How to parse? Give me an example please.

Comment: Why don't you post the contents of `myfile.m3u8`? Some simple string manipulation functions may be enough to parse it.

Comment: #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:420982
#EXTINF:5.0,
media-ughld59u3_b1800000_420982.ts
#EXTINF:5.0,
media-ughld59u3_b1800000_420983.ts
#EXTINF:5.0,
media-ughld59u3_b1800000_420984.ts

And this is the url
[link]http://dmivll.mangomolo.com/dubaione/smil:dubaione.smil/chunklist_b1800000.m3u8

Comment: The videos are hosted in your server, right? Just split lines, and remove query strings. You could avoid the .m3u8 file and just play `media-ughld59u3_b1800000_443944.ts` directly, but .ts is not supported by HTML5

Comment: it is like this to support different bandwidth

Comment: If you really need to support mobile, then you have to convert your videos to .mp4 or .webm You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)